# How to Completely Uninstall RUNDECK

Tags: error-handling, uninstallation, rundeck

I need a step by step procedure to uninstall RUNDECK. i am facing some STACK overflow issue which i wasn't able to resolve so i want to uninstall and install it from scratch

Stack error:

````
[2020-06-05 18:48:44.098] ERROR StackTrace --- [tp1284944245-71] Full Stack Trace:

org.grails.taglib.GrailsTagException: [views/layouts/base.gsp:184] Error executing tag <g:render>: [views/common/_sidebar.gsp:128] Error executing tag <g:ifMenuItems>: Method 'java.util.Set com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.authorization.providers.EnvironmentalContext.forProject(java.lang.String)' must be InterfaceMethodref constant
    at org.grails.gsp.GroovyPage.throwRootCause(GroovyPage.java:473)
    at org.grails.gsp.GroovyPage.invokeTag(GroovyPage.java:415)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor217.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.in```
````

Answer (score 3):

**WAR based instance:**

1. Make sure that the Rundeck process is down, identify the process
   doing `ps aux| grep -i rundeck` and use `kill -9 <PID>` to shut
   down.
2. Wipe the instance, you can delete all directory (and content)
   defined in `%RDECK_BASE%`. All configurations and files are inside
   this directory. If your system has a init script to launch rundeck, ensure that script doesn't have any reference to rundeck.
3. Re-install following [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/install/jar.html).

**RPM-based (CentOS, RHEL, Fedora) instance:**

1. Shutdown the Rundeck service: `# systemctl stop rundeckd`.
2. Make sure that the process is down: `# systemctl status rundeckd`.
3. Remove the package, do `# yum remove rundeck`.
4. Some files keep on the system, check and wipe the following paths:
   `/etc/rundeck`, `/var/lib/rundeck` and `/var/log/rundeck`.
5. Re-install following [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/install/linux-rpm.html#rundeck-enterprise).

**DEB-based (Debian, Ubuntu, Mint) instance:**

1. Shutdown the Rundeck service: `# systemctl stop rundeckd`.
2. Make sure that the process is down doing `# systemctl status rundeckd`.
3. Remove the package, do `# apt-get purge rundeck`
4. Some files keep on the system, check and wipe the following paths:
   `/etc/rundeck`, `/var/lib/rundeck` and `/var/log/rundeck`.
5. Reinstall following [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/install/linux-deb.html#install-with-apt-get).

Anyway, I recommend **to make a backup** of your instance / configurations before wiping it.

For testing the best option is to run [Rundeck docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/rundeck/rundeck), it saves a lot of time.

About the error, check your Rundeck version, maybe you're facing [this](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/4400#issuecomment-456985194) issue.

Comment: I tried removing and reinstalling it, but i am still facing the Same full stack error which u have linked, i am unable to resolve this

Comment: Which Rundeck version and JDK version are you using?

Comment: i am using rundeck : rundeck-3.2.6-20200427.war and java : java version “1.8.0_151

Comment: I tried with downloading older versions, but same issue persists, FULL STACK TRACE error. i started getting this error when i tried adding new acl.policies. i reverted back the changed i did, but still issue isnt solved.  Error log: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62153525/error-when-i-added-new-user-aclpolicy-error-stacktrace-tp1969073751-39-fu

Comment: Hi @Megadrive68K, i was able to fix my error, i downgraded JDK version to 1.8, works fine now